# How to iterate through rows and query specific fields based on the contents of other fields in the same row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've generated a tabular dataset and I'm trying to query and generate a report from it in xls format using python. I've got the data into a pandas dataframe and have all the potentially relevant fields lined up in the right order, now I need to select where specific columns within each row meets a specific criteria. If that criteria is met, I want to include a specific field from the same row. I'm just a bit lost on how I can query this dataset further.

```
  columns = ['type_1','price_1','color_1','type_2','price_2','color_2','type_3','price_3','color_3' ]

    1'Car','300','Grey','None','None','None,'Truck','500','blue'
    2'Van','250','White','Car','300','Green','Car','350','Black'
    3'None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None'
    4'None','None','None''Car','600','Yellow''None','None','None'
    5'Van','250','White','Car','300','Green','Van','250','White'
```

I want to query this dataset to output cars, and if cars, then include the price and color. So how can I iterate through the rows above and generate the output below using pandas?

```
    'Car','300','Grey'
    'Car','300','Green''Car','350','Black'
    'Car','600','Yellow'
    'Car','300','Green'
```

I get the feeling here are two approaches, query the dataset, peeling away where desired conditions are not met i.e.:

```
    df[df.type_1 != 'Car' OR df.type_2 != 'Car' OR df.type_3 != 'Car']
```

or create a new dataframe and write/append to it when the condition is met.

I'm brand new to pandas and it's functions, so a bit of guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What column do you want to retrieve when not none? You have several columns

Comment: His expected output is quite clear if you ask me.

Comment: @Rarblack 3 columns where the type= 'Car'.

for example, if type_1 = 'Car' give me 'Type_1', 'Price_1', 'Color_1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes several steps.

1. Filter columns bases on `_1`, `_2` and `_3`
2. Loop through dataframes and filter `type` columns on `'Car'`
3. `Concat` the dataframes together to one final dataframe

btw: I think your expected output should a bit adjusted to make sense:

```
df = df.replace("'None'", np.NaN)

df1 = df[df.filter(like='_1').columns]
df2 = df[df.filter(like='_2').columns]
df3 = df[df.filter(like='_3').columns]

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs_new = []
cntr = 1

for d in dfs:
    dfs_new.append(d[d['type_'+str(cntr)] == "'Car'"])
    cntr += 1

print(pd.concat(dfs_new, axis=1).fillna(''))
  type_1 price_1 color_1 type_2 price_2   color_2 type_3 price_3  color_3
0  'Car'   '300'  'Grey'                                                 
1                         'Car'   '300'   'Green'  'Car'   '350'  'Black'
3                         'Car'   '600'  'Yellow'                        
4                         'Car'   '300'   'Green'
```

**Note** I can get your expected output exactly the same, but that would not make sense since `type_1` and `type_2` cars are on top of each other, while `type_3` has its own column.

Comment: Thank you for your help Erfan. I would like to have the output table be left aligned if that makes sense. It would look something like this once everything was filtered out.
So what used to look like this:
X|O|O|O|O
O|X|O|O|O
X|O|X|O|X

Looks like this:
X
X
XXX

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. Please post a new question where you can explain better.

Comment: I can't get the first line of your code to successfully replace 'None' with NaN. I can't see an issue with your syntax either...
You've helped me get so close!

Comment: Check the spelling, is it `'None'` or `None`. Thats a difference. Right now it replaces `'None'`

Comment: That did the trick. Regarding the for d in dfs: loop. 
Its throwing a type error: invalid type comparison.  Does this mean Im missing a str() somewhere? All the columns in the df are strings.

Comment: Im mistaken, there are all objects except one is float. Is that potentially why the type comparison error is thrown?